# C binary tree struct

Tags: c, struct, binary-tree

I've just started to learn C and trying to make a binary tree with struct.
When I try to use addTreeNode in main() I get the following compile errors:
"Conflicting types for addTreeNode"
and "Passing 'BinaryTree' (aka 'struct BinaryTree') to parameter of incompatible type 'BinaryTree *' (aka 'struct *BinaryTree')"

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct BinaryTree
{
    int data;
    struct BinaryTree *left;
    struct BinaryTree *right;
};

typedef struct BinaryTree BinaryTree;

BinaryTree *addNode(int element, BinaryTree *tree);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    BinaryTree *tree;
    tree = addTreeNode(2, tree);

 return 0;
}

// add the given element element to the tree
BinaryTree *addTreeNode(int element, BinaryTree *tree)
{
    if (tree == NULL)
    {
        tree = malloc(sizeof(BinaryTree));
        tree->data = element;
    }
    else if (element < tree->data)
    {
        addTreeNode(element, tree->left);
    }
    else
    {
      addTreeNode(element, tree->right);
    }
    return tree;
}
```

Comment: Yet another question that I downvote after reading the title. Why do all these poor students have to write binary trees? And why do they have to write in C, while we're at it.

Comment: Well I guess it's a classic way to understand pointers and structs in C. For me it was linked lists in C:)

Comment: A canonical post on this error might be helpful... (although I don't think this should be it)

Comment: 2Bartek not my fault I was given this assignment.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Please, I don't really think you have enough experience to tell what's best to give students. This is an awesome exercise. Years after we have published stuff on trees, students still find it challenging. Also, learning about pointers is a timed-honored tradition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line

```
tree = addTreeNode(2, tree);
```

to

```
tree = addTreeNode(2, &tree);
```

Your function requires passing by pointer, yet you pass by value.

**EDIT:**

Since you are allocating your struct in function `BinaryTree *addTreeNode` you should change `BinaryTree tree;` to `BinaryTree *tree;` inside `main`. Also your function returns pointer to `BinaryTree*` which cannot be assign to a variable of type `BinaryTree`

Comment: Thanks. Now I have 'Conflicting types for addTreeNode' left. What does it mean?

Comment: My bad, it was BinaryTree *tree in my code from the beginning, so I guess I don't need the &-sign in the addTreeNode fuction. However, I still cannot assign tree pointer to the pointer returned by addTreeNode.

Comment: if that is the case, you do not

Comment: Still get the same error: "Passing 'BinaryTree' (aka 'struct BinaryTree') to parameter of incompatible type 'BinaryTree *' (aka 'struct *BinaryTree')". This is regardless of whether tree is a pointer.

Comment: did you check the addNode ad traverse functions?

Comment: All fixed and working now. Was just a bunch of obvious errors. Thanks for help!